# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring-boot

For the below code I am getting a 400 Bad Request

```
public String saveQuoteCall(String jsonObjectStr) {

            try {
                preparePostHttpEntity(jsonObjectStr);
                response = restTemplate.exchange(CREATE_QUOTE_URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
                log.info("Response : " + response.getStatusCode());
                if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                    return response.getBody();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in saveQuoteCall : ", e);
            }
            return "No Data";
        }

        private void preparePostHttpEntity(String sendingStr) {

            try {
                headers = new HttpHeaders();
                log.info("request in checkCDBalance preparePostHttpEntity: " + sendingStr);
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, ServiceSecurity.getHeaderValue());
                // log.info("request in checkCDBalance preparePostHttpEntity:
                // "+HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE);
                headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN }));
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                entity = new HttpEntity<String>(sendingStr, headers);
                log.info("entity value: " + entity);
                restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in preparePostHttpEntity : ", e);
            }
        }
```

Following is the stacktrace

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest:
>   400 Bad Request   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.restful.WebServiceCall.saveQuoteCall(WebServiceCall.java:58)
>   ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]     at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.quote.QuoteServices.saveQuoteService(QuoteServices.java:45)
>   [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]  at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.quote.QuoteServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4a211456.invoke()
>   [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
>   [spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
>   [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.quote.QuoteServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad148a87.saveQuoteService()
>   [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]  at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.quote.QuoteController.saveQuote(QuoteController.java:52)
>   [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1920.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   ~[na:1.8.0-internal]  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) ~[na:2.6
>   (07-22-2015)]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
>   [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.hcl.nic.portal.security.jwt.JwtOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtOncePerRequestFilter.java:65)
>   [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
>   [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
>   [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
>   [jps-ee.jar:na]   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:595)
>   [na:1.8.0-internal]   at
>   oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>   [jps-api.jar:na]  at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
>   [jps-ee.jar:na]   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
>   [jps-ee.jar:na]   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
>   [jps-ee.jar:na]   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
>   [jps-ee.jar:na]   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   oracle.security.wls.filter.SSOSessionSynchronizationFilter.doFilter(SSOSessionSynchronizationFilter.java:294)
>   [ssofilter.jar:na]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
>   [dms.jar:1.1.0-150927.0310]   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>   [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>   [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]    at
>   weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>   [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.0]   at
>   weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>   [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]  at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
>   [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
>   [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>   [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]

Answer (score 1):

> 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)

You got `400` response because of some sort of error in your request.

If you want to know more about it, you can debug the response you receive (represented by `ClientHttpResponse` object) in `DefaultResponseErrorHandler::handleError` method. You should be able to detect the problem yourself by looking into body of the response.